# Are there any false variants of the Collatz conjecture for which the probability heuristic works?

Tags: soft-question, divergence-operator, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

One of the supporting arguments for the Collatz conjecture is the [probability heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#A_probabilistic_heuristic), which states roughly that because the collatz operations tends to decrease numbers over time, it probably doesn't diverge.

Are there examples of where this isn't true, i.e. is there a variant of the collatz conjecture for which the probability heuristic holds, but not all numbers converge to a cycle? (Preferably, the set of numbers that diverge should be a [non-null set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set).)

Comment: How about 
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
n+3&\text{if}\;3{\,\mid\,}n\\
1&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The function which multiplies powers of two by 2 and all other numbers to 1 works, no? That heuristic is way too naive, methinks.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez then why do people believe in the collatz conjecture?

Comment: Surely not because of that heuristic! I honestly do not know why people believe in the conjecture, or even *if* they do, but there may well be many serious reasons to believe in it that lose no value because of this naive heuristic.

Comment: There is a set of numbers which under Collatz operations give a power of 2. $s=[1, 5, 21, 85,  . . . 4n+1]$ the sequence is infinite and all numbers lead to one of these numbers; some numbers may lead to huge numbers of this set under Collatz operations. So tending to small numbers is certain .

Comment: One strong reason to believe the conjecture is that there can be no isolated counterexample, so it's different to most problems where the probability heuristic can be dismissed on the grounds that some isolated counterexample might exist. But a counterexample to the Collatz Conjecture would be a member a set of counterexamples having non zero density in the integers

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}{\,\setminus}\{1\}$, with positive density less than $1/2$.

For $a \in A$, let $s(a)$ be the least element of $A$ which is greater than $a$.

Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
s(n)&\text{if}\;n\in A\\[4pt]
1&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then probabilistically, every iteration should cycle, but clearly, the iterations which start with an element of $A$, approach infinity.

Comment: Probabilistically most values cycle but on average this grows.

Comment: @Robert Frost: The OP only specified a probabilistic condition.

Comment: OP said tends to decrease over time. This tends to increase, provided we wrongly assume any number's behaviour is independent of its predecessor.

Comment: Instead of equality a 2nd case which falls to some fixed point would give you a falling heuristic.

Comment: @Robert Frost: Would the following variation satisfy your concept of "decreases on average"?
$$$$
Let $A$ be any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$, with positive density less than $1/2$. For $a \in A$, let $s(a)$ be the least element of $A$ which is greater than $a$. Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
s(n)&\text{if}\;n\in A\\
1&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Yes i think it's more in the spirit of the question because for any number selected at random the expected value of its successor is less than it. Although the flaw in the heuristic argument is that elements of sequences aren't selected independently of each other.

Comment: Fine, I'll edit in that change.